# How can I get a dynamic canvas element to sit behind other content within an offset div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm using [granim.js](https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/index.html) to generate a dynamically moving gradient in a `canvas`. I'd like to have it be the background content for a `div` element. Because granim.js generates content dynamically, using `canvas.toDataUrl()` doesn't work, and setting `position` to `absolute` or `relative` and setting `top/bottom/left/right` to `0` doesn't work, because the `div` is offset from the edge of the screen. I could calculate the absolute position using `.getBoundingClientRect()` and setting `top` that way (see bottom), but I felt like there had to be a more elegant solution. I've attached some code snippets below that hopefully help. Thanks!

HTML:

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="granim-wrapper">
      <canvas id="granim-canvas" height="565" width="837"></canvas>
    </div>

    <h1>This is some content.</h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  margin: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

JS:

```js
import Granim from "granim";

function resizeCanvas(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
  const main = document.querySelector('main');

  canvas.height = main.clientHeight;
  canvas.width = main.clientWidth;
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('granim-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
window.onresize = () => {resizeCanvas(canvas)};

window.onload = () => {
  resizeCanvas(canvas)

  const granimInstance = new Granim({
    element: "#granim-canvas",
    name: "granim",
    opacity: ["1", "1"],
    states: {
      "default-state": {
        gradients: [
          ["#8093F1", "#FDC5F5"],
          ["#B388EB", "#72DDF7"],
        ],
        loop: true,
      },
    },
    direction: 'diagonal',
  });
};
```

Solution using `.getBoundingClientRect()`:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main');
const rect = main.getBoundingClientRect();
const canvas = document.getElementById('granim-canvas');

canvas.style.top = `${rect.top}px`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the wrapper div to relative allows the inner h1 to be set to absolute with a top of 0 setting to the top of the wrapper div, as opposed to the page.

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>h1 {
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0;
}
```

Alternatively you could make the wrapper a `display: grid` and then use `grid-row` and `grid-column` to set both the text and the canvas to start and end at the same point in the grid, thus overlapping them.

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.wrapper>.granim-wrapper {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1; 
}

.wrapper>h1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1; 
}
```